# NodeJS, Mongoose, .save does not work

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, node.js

Не срабатывает сохранение новой коллекции

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
Schema = mongoose.Schema,
config = require(appRoot + '/config/config.js'),

// Category
Category = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        unique: true,
        required: true
    }
},{ collection: 'Category' });

Category.pre('save', function(next){
  console.log('PRESAVE',this);
  next();
});
Category.post('save', function(next){
  console.log('POSTSAVE')
})

module.exports  = mongoose.model('Category', Category);
```

Создание новой записи:

```
var category = new Category({
  name:"Test"
});
category.save(function(err){console.log(111,err)})
```

Вывод в консоле:

```
Mongoose: mpromise (mongoose's default promise library) is deprecated, plug in your own promise library instead: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/promises.h
tml
{ name: 'Test', subcategory: '1' }
PRESAVE { name: 'Test', _id: 57d1327ccad8e526347803de }
```

Без Category.pre тоже не работает